# Convert String to Postgres Timestamp and back

Tags: java, postgresql, timestamp

**Part 1:**

I have a file which contains date as string in the following format: `2006-02-16T21:36:32.000+0000`

I need to write this value to Postgres in a column which is of type `Timestamp`. How do I go about doing this in Java?

**Part 2:**

I need to read the value saved in Part 1 from Postgres, and convert it to a string of the following format `"2006-02-16T21:36:32.000+0000"`

---

This is what I have tried:

`Timestamp lastSyncDate = Timestamp.valueOf(2006-02-16T21:36:32.000+0000)`

When I try to write it to postgres, it gives me the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]`

Comment: Could you make the type of that column in Postgres `timestamp with time zone`? Since your string has a UTC offset. `+0000` means offset 0 from UTC. If not, you at least need to know or decide the time zone or UTC offset of your timestamps. If you can decide, I’d go for UTC.

Comment: Also avoid the `Timestamp` class, it is long outdated. Use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead. From that API, best to use `Instant` if you can, as in [Basil Bourque’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167459/5772882); if that won’t go, then `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    OffsetDateTime.parse( "2006-02-16T21:36:32.000+0000" )  
)
```

## With and without zone/offset

You said your column is of type `TIMESTAMP` which is short for `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. This type purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. *Not* usually appropriate for common business purposes.

### You are using wrong type

That is the **wrong type for your input**. Your input has an offset-from-UTC of zero hours which means UTC itself. Having an offset or zone, your data **should only be stored in a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`** type column. In this `…WITH…` type in Postgres, any submitted offset/zone info is used to adjust into UTC for storage, and then discarded.

Storing a date-time value with an offset or zone in a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` is like storing a price/cost with a designated currency( USD, Euros, Rubles, etc.) in a column of numeric type. You are losing vital data, the currency. This renders your data worthless.

See the [Postgres documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) for these types.

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

Whenever possible, use objects to exchange data with your database rather than passing meter strings. Let your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) do it’s job in [marshaling the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) back-and-forth.

Parse the input string as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

### ISO 8601

Your input strings are in a format defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2006-02-16T21:36:32.000+0000" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Define your SQL as a prepared statement.

With JDBC 4.2 and later, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database. No need to ever again use the troublesome legacy classes such as `java.sql.Timestamp`.

You could pass an `OffsetDateTime`. I like to extract an `Instant` to demonstrate to the reader that I understand how Postgres always stores a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value in UTC.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

`2006-02-16T21:36:32.000+0000` looks like a ISO-8601 timestamp. 
postgres understands this format. just treat it like any other string.

don't try to convert it into a java timestamp

Comment: Actually, passing that string to a column of type `TIMESTAMP` (as stated in the Question) results in data loss. The offset-from-UTC is ignored and discarded. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167459/642706) for details.